# Spring Apache Velocity encoding options

Tags: java, apache, velocity

Does anyone know where a definitive list can be found of the different encodings that can be used in Apache Velocity mergeTemplate method - or for that matter, the Spring VelocityEngineUtils mergeTemplateIntoString method? For example, I believe this "UTF-8" literal is correct, but is it really? And either way, what other options are there?

```
String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(
                velocityEngine, "email-templates/invalid-tx.vm", "UTF-8", model);
```

I haven't found a list of valid literals in the Velocity API documentation (https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/Velocity.html) nor that for VelocityEngineUtils (http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineUtils.html).

Comment: Aren't they standard Java encodings?

Comment: Dave N., that may be. If so, would that be from this list?: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html